# angular.mock.module and angular.mock.inject functions are not working in jasmine's beforeAll

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I want to use jasmine's beforeAll instead of beforeEach but angular.mock.module and angular.mock.inject functions are not working in beforeAll whereas they're working in beforeEach.

Here is my test. **the same code is working in beforeEach approach.**

```
describe("This is a test", function () {
    beforeAll(module("app"));

    var vm;
    beforeAll(function() {
        angular.mock.module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.factory("dataService", ["$q", function ($q) {
                return {
                    getSomeDataById: function () { return $q.resolve({ }); }
                };
            }]);
        });

        angular.mock.inject(function (_$controller_,dataService) {
            vm = _$controller_("TestController",
            {
                dataService: dataService
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar problem and using the [module.sharedInjector()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module.sharedInjector) call resolved it for me:

```
describe("This is a test", function () {

    // Call SharedInjector before any call that might invoke the injector
    angular.mock.module.sharedInjector();

    beforeAll(module("app"));

    var vm;
    beforeAll(function() {
        angular.mock.module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.factory("dataService", ["$q", function ($q) {
                return {
                   getSomeDataById: function () { return $q.resolve({ }); }
               };
            }]);
        });

        angular.mock.inject(function (_$controller_,dataService) {
            vm = _$controller_("TestController",
            {
                dataService: dataService
            });
        });
    });
});
```

A quick snippet from the [linked docs page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module.sharedInjector) to explain why that works (emphasis mine):

> [`angular.mock.module.sharedInjector`] ensures a single injector will be used for all tests in a given describe context. This contrasts with the default behaviour where a new injector is created per test case.
>
> **Use sharedInjector when you want to take advantage of Jasmine's beforeAll()**, or mocha's before() methods. Call module.sharedInjector() before you setup any other hooks that will create (i.e call module()) or use (i.e call inject()) the injector.

Comment: Added the context from the docs link you provided. Hope that's okay! Makes it an even stronger answer imo. Couldn't google this up to save my life; thanks.